# Task bar is not appearing when using CMFCVisualManagerVS2005 in my MFC application

Tags: mfc, taskbar

I'm developing an application for Windows using MFC in Visual Studio 2010. I'm using CMFCVisualManagerVS2005 to change the visual appearance of my application. When I run my application its hiding Windows task bar by opening my application in maximized state. I have to open my Application in maximized state so I have disabled maximize button.

Any idea how can I run my application in maximized state without hiding Windows task bar??

Answer (score 0):

Right click the empty space on your task bar -> properties -> ensure "Keep the taskbar on top of other windows" is checked. Hopefully this is your issue

Comment: "Keep the taskbar on top of other windows" is checked but my application is hiding task bar. If I change visual appearance of my Application by using CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007 then its showing task bar.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try placing the following code in CMainFrame::OnCreate(). I know it would be best to find the underlying issue, but this may suffice as a dirty fix.

```
HWND hTBar=::FindWindow("Shell_traywnd","");

::ShowWindow(hTBar,SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: let me know if this works. I am assuming your task bar is being hidden as opposed to just being "covered up" by your application window.